# Android Standard Pre-Material Design Icons library

Tags: android

Google offers a standard set of Material Design icons for Android 5.0: http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

However, I would like to use icons consistent with KitKat.  Does Google have their icons for download somewhere for earlier versions of Android?  I can't find them on their developer site.

Answer (score 2):

**Do you have the Android SDK?**
If not download it from here [Adding SDK Packages](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html)

Google provides all the resources, including icons, with the Android SDK under the `platforms` forlder. The complete location is `YOUR_BASE_LOCATION\android-sdk\platforms`

**How to locate the icons?**
Suppose you are looking for the icons that belongs to Android 4.0 (ICS), API 14 than you should look into the folder `YOUR_BASE_LOCATION\android-sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res\drawable-mdpi` here `android-14` refers to the Android API 14 i.e. [Android 4.0](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html). Also the `drawable-mdpi` refers to the Medium Dots Per Inch(MDPI). For higher screen resolutions refer to the corresponding drawable-hdpi and drawable-xhdpi folders.

**The folder is huge, how to locate / map the icons with Android 5.0 icons?**
Refer to the website [android drawables](http://androiddrawables.com/) and select the **Drawable Resources by Type** at the bottom. The next screen will display the icon file name and the comparison chart.

Hope that helps...
Happy Coding..

Answer (score 1):

can be found here, I use the second option to have more icons

https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icons-for-android

OR

https://materialdesignicons.com/

Comment: These are the standard Material Design icons that I linked to in my question.  I am looking for the icons that were standard in Android 4.x, not 5.x.

Comment: when you click on the icon will show the option 4.x  https://materialdesignicons.com/

Comment: Thanks, but that gives you the image in a collection of formats suitable for use in Android 4.x.  I don't want icons that look like those in Material Design; I want the icons that look like the standard icons from Android 4.x.  I solved my problem by recycling the icons I needed from another project.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the old ActionBar (Holo styled) icon pack that was on the official Android developer website [here](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20120814.zip).

This [github repo](https://github.com/svenkapudija/Android-Action-Bar-Icons/tree/master/Android%20Stock) also has the Holo styled icons.

Answer (score 1):

although it is a few Irrelevant but  you can use this useful tool

```
http://android-holo-colors.com/
```